# How can I find Kth element in a m*n matrix that each rows(m) are in order with O(m(log m +log n))

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures

suppose that we have a m*n matrix that each rows are in order. so, i only know that order of best algorithm for this problem is O(m(log m + log n)). 
(It was a test question and result is this order)
but i don't know how this algorithm works

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. It also isn't clear to me what it means that the "rows are in order".

Comment: each rows are sorted (not columns). and we want to find Kth element in this matrix

Comment: Are you sure it can be done in `O(m(log m + log n))` ? It can be definitely done in `O((m+n)log m)`.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible and i think this question extracted from an article

Comment: @SomeDude, what is the `O((m+n)log m)` solution please?

Comment: @kaya3 this problem is clear

Answer (score 1):

One idea can be like this.

If I ask you what is the rank of a given number `x` in the original matrix? How do you answer this question?
One answer can be:

Just binary search the first occurrence of `x` or greater element on each row. and then add the individual ranks.

```
int rank = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    rank += std::lower_bound(matrix[i].begin(), matrix[i].end(), x);
}
```

This can be done in O(m * log n) time(m binary searches on n sized arrays). 
Now we just need to do a binary search on x(between 0 and INT_MAX or `matrix[0][k]`) to find the kth rank. Since INT_MAX is const, that will make the overall time complexity O(m * log n) theoretically. One optimization, which can be done use intelligent ranges in place of `matrix[i].begin(), matrix[i].end()`.

**PS**: Still wondering the `O(m*(log m + log n))` or `O( m * (log mn))` solution.

Comment: Not sure why you are computing rank ? There is no given element , you need to compute the kth smallest element from all the elements in the matrix as per OP. no?

Comment: @SomeDude Exactly

Comment: @v78 your solution is not correct

Comment: @SomeDude, I created a subproblem(rank of `x`) above and `x` is a parameter in that and used that to solve ur problem(by doing binary search on `x`),